# Can we move SharePoint up in the site hierarchy?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, wss

I have SharePoint with the local intranet link as http://shserver/Sites/LAPP/HR/LA. I want to move the site LA to the following location http://shserver/Sites/LAPP/LA.

Is this possible through some tool or the only way is to recreate the site altogether in the new url location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

STSAdmin should help out here - [this article](http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/blogs/fromthefield/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=0ce77946%2D1e45%2D4b43%2D8c74%2D21963e64d4e1&ID=26) looks to cover what you would need